# How to remove item equal to some value from list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I need to remove all `item[0]` if `a` is `== '1'`:

```
a = [['1','2','3'], ['2','4','9']]
for item in a:
    if item[0] == '1':
        del item
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to ask questions , mind the typos, give some details instead of just posting some random thoughts in order to get proper help

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension as follows

```
a = [i for i in a if i[0] != '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not change length of list while iterating over it. make new list instead.

```
b = [i for i in a if i[0] != '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`:

```
new_a = list(filter(lambda item: item[0] != '1', a))
```

The list is just so its compatible regardless of your python version (`filter` returns lazy sequence in python3).

Answer (score 0):

A List Comprehension is the best way to solve this problem but if you want to use a for loop here's some Python code for that:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [2,1,9], [1,6,9], [5,6,7]]
# Code
def removeOneList(a):

    for item in a:
       if item[0] == 1:
           del item[:]

    return a

print(removeOneList(a))
```